# How to get the element html clicked in a ngFor to add a css class?

Tags: angular

I have this *ngFor*:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of aCategory" (click)="fn_qualify($event)">
 {{item.name}} 
</div>
```

and I would like that when you click, get the current element, and once you have obtained it, you can add a class ("categoria_seleccionada"). I am very used to using *document.querySelector*, but I want to be sure to do the best practice. How can I do it? Thank you.

```
fn_qualify(element){
 console.log(element.target);
 //console.log(document.querySelector(element.target)); //I am getting error
 //.addClass("categoria_seleccionada");
}
```

I will explain my problem more thoroughly. I have an array called "aCategory".

```
this.aCategory=
[
  {"name":"AUTORIZAR","class":"" },
  {"name":"CAMBIO","class":"" },
  {"name":"CAMBIO FACTURA","class":"" }
.
.
.

<div *ngFor="let item of aCategory" (click)="fn_qualify(item)" [ngClass]="item.class">
```

has this structure, and may have "n" elements. If I click on an element of the ngFor, I could add it to this element:

```
fn_qualify(item){
  item.class="category_selected"
}
```

and I could use *[ngClass]*

but my goal is that when you click on an element, only this one has that class, and the rest does not. so I want to avoid doing a *for cycle* to set the "class" property of my array to "".

Comment: for the current item, you can do `(click)="fn_qualify(item)"` but what kind of class are you trying to add? is it a css class? is it ts method?

Comment: I mean the html element. I need to get it to add a class. I need add a css class..

Comment: why not use ngClass ?

Comment: If you are calling a method just to add class attribute, then you need not call a function either. Check this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ruerb9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: thanks @rhavelka,   I updated the question ,I hope you understand me..

Comment: @AmitChigadani your answer, not works for me..

Comment: @user5115790 I have also added an answer with respect to your updated question. Please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like this. 
I'm passing the item and the index.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of aCategory; let i = index">
 <div (click)="fn_quality(item, i)">{{item.name}} 
</div>
```

Second option

Add a variable to your Ts file. 
Like `active:any = ''`
And then just simply

```
<div *ngFor="let item of aCategory; let i = index">
     <div (click)="active = i" [ngClass]="active === i ? 'myCssClass' : '' " >{{item.name}} 
    </div>
```

Comment: I mean the html element. I need to get it to add a css class.

Comment: But if you need a class just use [ngClass] on the current Item using the current Index

Answer (score 0):

```
// this will set the class categoria_seleccionada when this item's 'selected' attribute is set to true
<div *ngFor="let item of aCategory" (click)="fn_qualify(item)" [class.categoria_seleccionada]="item.selected">
 {{item.name}} 
</div>
```

In the component

```
fn_qualify(item: any) : void {
   // first deselect the currently selected item, if any
   for (let i = 0 ; i < this.aCategory.length; i++) {
      this.aCategory[i].selected = false;
   }

   // find the index of the current clicked item and set the selected value to true
   let item = this.aCategory.filter(i => i._id === item._id)[0];
   let index = this.aCategory.indexOf(item);
   this.aCategory[index].selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this as your html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of aCategory; i = index" (click)="fn_qualify(i)" [ngClass]="item.class">
 {{item.name}} 
</div>
```

Set this as your typescript

```
previouslyActive = 0;
fn_qualify(index){
  this.aCategory[this.previouslyActive].class = '';
  this.aCategory[index].class = "categoria_seleccionada";
  this.previouslyActive = index;
}
```

now you have your class updating on the element, whatever was previously active is no longer active, and you don't have an expensive for loop

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like this. Just pass an index parameter to the function. Add and remove `class` accordingly.

```
fn_qualify(index) {
    this.aCategory.forEach((item, i) => {
      if (i == index) {
        this.aCategory[i].class = 'categoria_seleccionada';
      }
      else {
         this.aCategory[i].class = '';
      }
    })
}
```

html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of aCategory; let i = index;" (click)="fn_qualify(i)" [ngClass]="item.class">
 {{item.name}} 
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ruerb9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="let item of aCategory; let i = index" (click)="fn_qualify(i)" [ngClass]="{'selected': currentIndex === i}">
 {{item.name}} 
</div>
```

In your ts:

```
public currentIndex:number;

public fn_quality(index:number) {
this.currentIndex = index;
}
```